# Using whose with non-human?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, grammaticality

The numbers are non human. I have this sentence where it uses whose to refer to the numbers. Is this sentence correct? If not, any suggestions?

> We do not receive 100% replies for the numbers whose metadata we query
>   from the search engine.

Comment: Do you have a source which says that "whose" (meaning of whom or which) must relate to a human?

Comment: Might be of interest: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/can-whose-refer-to-an-inanimate-object

Comment: @James K No. It just does not sound familiar to me with non-human.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good usage. See:
[American Heritage Dictionary "whose" (2)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=whose)

1. The possessive form of who.
2. The possessive form of which.

The definition has a long usage note about using "whose" as possessive of "which", referring to inanimate objects.

Comment: So the short answer is "whose" can be used with non-human as in my example?

Comment: Yes, with plenty of precedent by writers in history (per the usage note).